# Verilog [cross module resolution error] when expanding the definitions

Tags: compiler-errors, verilog, system-verilog, hdl, asic

I've been getting a cross-module resolution error, when the compiler expands the definition as follow:

in file, say path_defines.vh (where the definitions is at):

```
`define apple aaaa.bbbb.cccc.\pie[0] .dddd.eeee
```

I'm using the "\" character accompanied by a tailing "white-space" to escape the characters "[" and "]" as defined in the 2012 verilog manual.

So when the compiler parses a file(say eg: design.vs) with the defined term as seen here :

```
`apple.ffff.gggg
```

and tries to expand the definition, the compiler gives me a :

Cross-module reference resolution error.

Error found while trying to resolve cross-module reference.

Comment: it tells you that the signal does not exist. apparently you have a bug in your path. Besides, why exactly do you use the 'escape name'?  the compiler does not generate those. I do not think that you need it there.

Comment: Since I used the "[]" characters in the definition names, I need to use the "\" and a tailing white space to escape the "[]" characters

Comment: perhaps i should clarify, would the Synopsys DC compiler have a problem with escape characters ?

Answer (score 0):

If your example is similar to the below, you do **not** need any escape name. The compiler will understand pie[0] as a part of the name. `[]` are ok there.

```
module top;
    aaa aaa();       
    assign aaa.bbb.pie[0].ccc.ddd = 0;
endmodule
module aaa();
    bbb bbb();
endmodule 
module bbb;
    generate
      for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) begin: pie
         ccc ccc();
      end
   endgenerate
endmodule // bbb
module ccc;
   wire ddd;
endmodule
```

Comment: oh okay, good to know. However I don't think this would solve the definitions expansion error though :(

Comment: You need to provide your example. expansion has nothing to do with cross-module references, it is just a macro substitution.

Comment: perhaps i should clarify, would the Synopsys DC compiler have a problem with escape characters ?

Comment: it should not,.